# While using formArray I am getting this error: "ModalDialogComponent.html:6 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of null"

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I want to add dynamic elements using reactive forms in angular. I am following this link: https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/.

I am doing exact similar to that link. But I am getting error.
Below is the code:

**ts file:**

```
orderForm: FormGroup;
items: FormArray;
```

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      iems: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createItem() ])
    })
  }

createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      checked: ''
    })
  }

addDynamicCheckBox() {
    this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    this.items.push(this.createItem());
  }
```

**template file:**

```
<div [formGroup]="orderForm">
        {{ orderForm.controls.items.controls }}
      <div class="row" formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls; let i=index">
        <div class="col-10" [formGroupName]="i">
          <mat-checkbox formControlName="checked"></mat-checkbox>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2" style="float: right">
          <button mat-raised-button>Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Edit**

I want to set values of formArray controls. I am not able to see any value. Just check box is display. Following code I made:

**ts file**

```
setCheckBoxValue() {
    this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    this.data.data.forEach((element) => {
      this.items.push(this.formBuilder.group({
        checked: true,
        selected: element
      }))
    });
  }
```

**html file**

```
<div [formGroup]="orderForm">
      <div class="row" formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls; let i=index">
        <div class="col-8" [formGroupName]="i">
          <mat-checkbox formControlName="checked">{{item.checked}}</mat-checkbox>
        </div>
      </div>

      check box value: {{ orderForm.get('items').controls.checked }}
    </div>
``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a typo in your code *iems* -> **items** . Please see the updated answer

**TS File**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  orderForm: FormGroup;
  items: FormArray;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      items: this.formBuilder.array([this.createItem()])
    })
  }

  createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      checked: true
    })
  }

  addDynamicCheckBox() {
    this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    this.items.push(this.createItem());
  }

  setCheckBoxValue() {
    this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    this.items.push(this.formBuilder.group({
      checked: true,
    }))
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
<div [formGroup]="orderForm">
    <div class="row" formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls; let i=index">
        <div class="col-8" [formGroupName]="i">
            <input type="checkbox" formControlName="checked" />
        I'm {{item.controls.checked.value === true ? "Checked" : "Unchecked"}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <button (click)="setCheckBoxValue()">Add</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hello @Sharan, I want to set values of form array elements. I edited my question. I am just able to see checkbox not its value. Can you please check my updated code?

Comment: https://angular-radfs1.stackblitz.io/ : Check this stackblitz. I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you so much.. @Sharan, I am using *item* from ngFor.. so nothing is showing me up.. But I want to ask that why I am not getting any value by using item?

Comment: You can use item as well, I've updated the answer. Please see to it. If it helped you please mark the answer as correct

Comment: Okay, it is displaying values using item too.  But by doing unchecked it is showing false and again by checking it, it is showing true. This should not be happened, right? By checking or unchecking the checkbox, value should not be changed

Comment: What you mean, values should not be changed? It should change

Comment: Yes @Sharan, you right. value should change and it is changing. But as per my project requirement, I have to display data in check boxes from API response. So I added one more field in form array. And by using that field I am facing trouble.

Comment: If you need to show the values from a data source (api response in this case), then you need to patch the values. Refer https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#patchvalue

Comment: Okay, thank you @Sharan, for your efforts. But I tried with setValues() and it is working properly but getting error like **ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'Doktor nauka'**. So do I need to change to patchValues() for better output?

Comment: Setvalue and Patchvalue are methods from the Angular Formgroup. They both set the value of a control in a formgroup. The clear difference is that setvalue cannot exclude some controls while the patchvalue is able to do just that.